# How to ng-repeat over array with arrays as elements?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a array like this:

```
   $scope.sortable = [["inProgressCounter","31"],["approvedCounter","3"],["pendingCounter","35"],["rejectedCounter","0"]]

I need to show them with ng-repeat my code is:
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="info in sortable">{{info[0]}}{{info[1]}}</li>
</ul>
```

but it gives me nothing.
so I also tried print the data out in html like this:

```
{{sortable}}
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="info in sortable">{{info[0]}}{{info[1]}}</li>
    </ul>
```

it works,and shows me the data.

Comment: can you post your controller code, where are you assigning $scope.sortable ?

Comment: I may know what you think, I tried this :{{sortable}} <ul>
 <li ng-repeat="info in sortable">{{info[0]}}{{info[1]}}</li>
</ul> it shows the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plunker of this working. This was all using the code you provided.

There must be something wrong with your controller, or you arent even assigning a controller to anything.

```
code
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4pEsP6mr0tA6Toe9coTG?p=preview